# Interface Builder - Custom Button with Title text

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

When I set up a custom button in Interface Builder it hides the Title text.

Do you have to create the text for the button too or is it possible to change the Z order so that the Title appears on top?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably setting the 'Image' property of your button instead of the 'Background' property.
'Image' appears over your text, so either programmatically or in NIB(way simpler), set the 'Background' image to your desired png, and set the text for the desired button 'State Config'(default, selected etc), Leaving the 'Image' property blank.

Answer (score 0):

The title by default appears on the top and in no case the text goes behind the button... 
Still follow the below steps
1. Drag uibutton to the view
2. Select UIButton
3. Click on the first tab of the Inspector
4. Then Enter the title over there.

The title entered will be on the button..
Hope this helps

Comment: Your answer would be fine for a standard button. 
However, if I use a custom button as I mentioned (i.e. use my own PNG) then the PNG appears but I cannot see the Title.

Comment: Well in that case .... I suppos u have set the Image of the button and not the Background Image...

Try setting your png file in the Bacground property just below the Image property...

Answer (score 0):

For a custom button, I fixed the same problem by going in interface builder and in the tab where you can set up hte title, image, background, etc., if you look lower, there will be a section titled "Control". In that section you can change the alignment and there are also some checkboxes for "Content". Put a checkmark in "Enabled" and "Selected" and it should work. Ensure to have populated the title for the various states of the button.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the State Config attribute. I had the same problem and solved it by doing this:

1. Select your button
2. In the utilities pane (right pane), select the Attribute inspector (4th tab).
3. Change the State Config (2nd attribute) to the value "Default".
4. Enter a Title and press Enter (I tried changing it directly on the button but it is resized automatically).
5. You may switch back to your previous State Config if it is what you need.